# Sending a message from web server to logged in client

Tags: html, jakarta-ee, servlets, client-server

I have a Java Servlet as controller and html pages as Views. In the application I have two login types. 1) Admin 2) Operator.

When Operator sends some request, if Admin is logged in, it needs to send the message to Admin.

I am able to post the message to Servlet. But from Servlet (Server), how I can send a message to Admin (ie a client). While session is requested, do we need to store some where and use that to send message?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `response.getWriter().println("ABC");` in servlet to write output to client

Comment: No. It wont work. I want to communicate from One client to another. Like Java Web Chat client. One client sends a message to another but through http only.

Comment: That will not work. HTTP is a client server technology, not a peer to peer one. If you are using HTTP you will have to go via the server. Then there is the issue that HTTP does not support server push. You will need to use some other technology on top of HTTP to achieve that.

Comment: Oh. I thing I need to go for a polling mechanism where I can get the messages from server. Is all web based chat client's uses polling? It will not receive message from server directly?